# Does a process know whether a system resource is used by other process? How can I cleanup the system resource safely?

Tags: resources, system

The question comes from: [RAII and system resource cleanup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6673899/raii-and-system-resource-cleanup)

Actually cleanup system resource is hard. In my mind, a process can't "know" whether a system resource(**file, message queue, semaphore, shared memory**) is used by other process or not. If it's true, how to guarantee to cleanup system resource safely?

If that is no a reliable way to do that, how can we do? Are there some common ways for it?